# Getting notified on Streaming Events in Apex?

Tags: trigger, platform-event, streaming-api, event-monitoring

I need to be notified on the following events:

```
LightningUriEventStream
LoginAsEventStream
LoginEventStream
ReportAnomalyEvent
SessionHijackingEvent
```

I know in LWC and Aura components I can use the emp API to get notified etc. However I need to have some options in Apex. Doing some research I see that one can do Apex triggers on events as mentioned here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_auth_create_logout_event_trigger.htm&type=5

Is this the only way to subscribe to events in Apex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Apex triggers are the way to go.
The streaming APIs rely on the CometD protocol and there is no CometD client available in Apex.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Transaction Security Policy for getting notifications on real-time events. Refer:[Transaction Security Policies](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.enhanced_transaction_security_policy_types.htm&type=5)